# ASP.NET The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relat

Tags: asp.net, ssl, httpwebrequest

When attempting to use HttpWebRequest to retrieve a page from my dev server, I get a web exception:

The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure...

The url I'm attempting to read from is a plain-old http://myserver.com/mypage.asp - no SSL. The production server has a valid certificate so this shouldn't be an issue, but our dev server doesn't.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good answer here:

http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically/

Not good for production, but solves my dev server problem.

Comment: What is the security risk of using this in production?

Comment: @Amjad Using an invalid SSL certificate in production? Well, it makes your site look like a scam or a phishing expedition, to start with. Shrug.

Comment: Well in my case we do not have a website. Rather we are using PowerShell to communicate / create resources on Azure. We used a similar code to trust all certificates within the PowerShell session.

Comment: @Amjad then the risk is that, due to some malicious party between your PS app and Azure, that you're not actually talking to Azure. The point of the certificate is for the remote entity to prove that they are who they say they are.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the link that @DavidLively provided is no longer available. You can find it using the archive of the Web: http://web.archive.org/web/20120830211353/http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically/

Also, from that code I did this to allow any certificate, valid or not (DO NOT use this in production code!):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAnyCertificate);

private static bool AcceptAnyCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 since 2009, I've started putting the code actually *in* the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this issue even after adding the certificate to your test server's trusted root certification authorities, make sure it is added for all users not just the current user only.

More information:
http://brainof-dave.blogspot.com/2008/08/remote-certificate-is-invalid-according.html